# missing pointer cv qualification in parameter function, partial template specialization

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-templates, template-specialization, qualifiers

Struct Name is used to convert type declaration into a string. When testing a logic error occurs, when the type declaration is a function type (or type of pointer function) and has a parameter type declaration of pointer function with qualification (`const, volatile, const volatile`). The qualifier is missing from pointer function type in the function parameter. For more details can see the `code` below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
```

#### Forward declaration of template struct Name :

```
template<typename T>
struct Name;
```

#### Struct Parameter

To split parameters from declarator of function type.

```
template<typename... Targs>
struct Parameter
{
    static void ToString(std::string& str, bool first = true)
    {}
};

template<typename Targ, typename... Targs>
struct Parameter<Targ, Targs...>
{
    static void ToString(std::string& str, bool first = true)
    {
        if (!first)
            str += ", ";
        str += Name<Targ>::ToString();
        Parameter<Targs...>::ToString(str, false);
    }
};
```

#### Struct Declarator

To classify the type of declaration with partial template specialization.

```
template<typename T>
struct Declarator
{
    typedef T RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Declarator<T*>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        ptr_str_stack.push("*");
        Declarator<T>::ToString(str, ptr_str_stack);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Declarator<T*const>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        ptr_str_stack.push("*const");
        Declarator<T>::ToString(str, ptr_str_stack);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Declarator<T*volatile>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        ptr_str_stack.push("*volatile");
        Declarator<T>::ToString(str, ptr_str_stack);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Declarator<T*const volatile>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        ptr_str_stack.push("*const volatile");
        Declarator<T>::ToString(str, ptr_str_stack);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
struct Declarator<T(*)(Targs...)>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        str += "(*";
        while(!ptr_str_stack.empty())
        {
            str += ptr_str_stack.top();
            ptr_str_stack.pop();
        }
        str += ")(";
        Parameter<Targs...>::ToString(str);
        str += ")";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
struct Declarator<T(*const)(Targs...)>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        str += "(*const";
        while(!ptr_str_stack.empty())
        {
            str += ptr_str_stack.top();
            ptr_str_stack.pop();
        }
        str += ")(";
        Parameter<Targs...>::ToString(str);
        str += ")";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
struct Declarator<T(*volatile)(Targs...)>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        str += "(*volatile";
        while(!ptr_str_stack.empty())
        {
            str += ptr_str_stack.top();
            ptr_str_stack.pop();
        }
        str += ")(";
        Parameter<Targs...>::ToString(str, true);
        str += ")";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
struct Declarator<T(*const volatile)(Targs...)>
{
    typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType RemovedType;
    static void ToString(std::string& str, 
        std::stack<std::string>& ptr_str_stack)
    {
        str += "(*const volatile";
        while(!ptr_str_stack.empty())
        {
            str += ptr_str_stack.top();
            ptr_str_stack.pop();
        }
        str += ")(";
        Parameter<Targs...>::ToString(str, true);
        str += ")";
    }
};
```

#### Struct Type

To classify the type of name with explicit template specialization.

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
    static void ToString(std::string& str)
    {
        str += typeid(T).name();
    }
};

template<>
struct Type<int>
{
    static void ToString(std::string& str)
    {
        str += "int";
    }
};
```

#### Definition template struct Name

To convert type declaration into a string.

```
template<typename T>
struct Name
{
    static std::string ToString()
    {
        
        typedef typename Declarator<T>::RemovedType SimpleType;
        std::string str;
        std::string declarator_str;
        std::stack<std::string> declarator_ptr_str_stack;
        Type<SimpleType>::ToString(str);
        Declarator<T>::ToString(declarator_str, declarator_ptr_str_stack);
        while(!declarator_ptr_str_stack.empty())
        {
            str += declarator_ptr_str_stack.top();
            declarator_ptr_str_stack.pop();
        }
        str += declarator_str;
        return str;
    }
};
```

#### main test

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Name<int(*)(int(*)())>::ToString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Name<int(*const)(int(*const)())>::ToString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Name<int(*volatile)(int(*const volatile)())>::ToString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Name<int(*const volatile)(int(*volatile)())>::ToString() << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output(gcc):

```
int(*)(int(*)())
int(*const)(int(*)())
int(*volatile)(int(*)())
int(*const volatile)(int(*)())
```

Comment: Top-level CV-qualifiers are dropped from parameter types for function arguments. I think that's what is happening here.

Comment: You might want to checkout what `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().prettyName()` does.